# Why do I receive this error when I use LINQ in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a table named Student in my linq in model folder. When I run my app and I click on student tab this error appears on IE. I don’t have any idea why I see this.

**Compiler Error Message:**

> CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

**Source Error:**

> Line 27:
>   Line 28:
>   Line 29:     public class _Page_Views_Student_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage> {
>   Line 30:
>   Line 31: #line hidden

**Source File:**

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\682ba75a\2833b27b\App_Web_index.cshtml.b4fd288c.t7qdtf0f.0.cs    Line: 29

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what to do.

Comment: That "reference" from the error message must be added to the web project.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a reference to System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 in your project. Pretty much as the error is saying.

`You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.`

You can do this by either right clicking the project and clicking Add Reference and navigating to System.Data.Linq or you can do it manually in your Web.Config.

Comment: thank you so much but , could you guide me how to add this reference ,where should I find it ?

Comment: If you right click your project in Solution Explorer > Add Reference... and then the assembly you're looking for can be found under Assemblies > Framework.